# Can I please get the data sheet for an IC in a blood pressure monitor, am trying to hack the data and send to cloud. JL Ic with number AC21CMDY9T-2B4

Tags: power-electronics, instrumentation

This is the IC image, I need to hack the blood pressure monitor. The name of the model is KWL-W01

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: why do you need this proprietary info?

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer? Even so, I’m with @Tony on this.

Comment: There is no image in your post

Comment: Highly likely it runs some software you won't be able to read

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75, I need it to hack the device, am working on an IoT based patient health monitoring system which measures the blood pressure, body temperature and heart rate then send the data to the cloud., this IC is from the blood pressure monitor needed to be hack to configure this

Comment: @Pete Hooper I think the manufacturer of the chip is Toshiba, although have sent an email to a company if am able to get it

Comment: As I said earlier am looking if the component have an I2C eeprom if I can get the data from it, but it doesn't have what I saw there doesn't look like I2C

Comment: @Scott Weidman., you can click in the link to see the picture I added to it., will also be adding another picture that I think its the I2C but not it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's very likely to be a custom microcontroller or ASIC.  You'll likely have a hard time hacking it to the extent that you can find the numbers you need.

I'd say the easier way to do it would be to find the analog output of the pressure sensor, T it off in a way it won't interfere with the device functionality,  and use your own microcontroller to find the blood pressure.  However, you'd be looking for very tiny vibrations riding on a larger signal, and it will be difficult.

If you were a student of mine, and you absolutely, positively, had to get this done, I'd be suggesting capturing the screen with a camera and using image processing to pull out the numbers you need.  I'd start with a small Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

If it has an I2C EPROM, like the BR24L02W from Rohm, you are in luck.

- add ESP8266 and your own firmware with extra battery and you have a wireless solution.
- You may want to get a protocol analyzer with an I2C adapter, such as https://www.ikalogic.com/scanastudio/

Then decide on protocol from analyzing the messages, create a memory map from new (reset) of all variables you want that are dynamic and averaged with limits. And Bob's your uncle.  No not quite that easy but if you know how to design one, then it's easier to reverse engineer.

Important project aspects to avoid

```
poor change control
lack of proper initial identification of what is required to bring about the project objectives
weak project manager or executive sponsor
poor communication between parties
lack of initial product versatility
```

Ref: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep